# UItableview auto height bug when label constraint to bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Im using a UItableview with auto height, i have 3 labels : label, sublabel and price. on top of the table i have a view attached to the bottom of screen. when scrolling the table down, it auto hides, when coming back up it shows again (kinda mimics safari functionality..) , heres comes the glitch. if i pin the sublabel to the bottom. ( as everybody knows if you are using cell auto height you have to.. otherwise the text will just mess up and the height of the cell won't change... . my bottom bar view will hide when scrolling , but when scrolling some more it glitches and pops back out for half a second, this only happens only when time, that first time the view appears...

im kind of stuck on this, i cannot unpin the sublabel, cause it will mess the cell height, etc. and i cannot have this glitch on messing up either... is there another way to make the auto height on cell work ?

[image: basic layout]

This is the basic layout. as you can see.. normal table view a a view on top which fixes to the bottom.
[image: Constraints contentview]
constraints.
[image: sublabel] 
Everything has their constraints for good. In this picture i deleted the bottom constraint and the top constraint to Label of the sublabel (i decided just not to display the sublabel text while i figure this bug out..) Thats when the bug happen (if enabled). In this in table im using auto/ dynamic height. the label and the sublabel are settled lines to 0, wordwrap by word and they have their constraints ok. i have a mechanism that when user scrolls down. the Bottom bar hides down, if the user comes back to top of the table, the bottom bar shows up. so the thing is, for the uitable cell to auto height u really need 2 must constraints. one top, one bottom. if i eliminate the bottom constraints like in the pic. the bug from the bottom bar flicking disappears but i don't get my table cell auto weighted so the text will mess up... if enabled then i get the flicking bug one time, that first load. then it works normally

Comment: can you please attach any image of your view and constraints

Comment: @Bhavini just uploaded some pics and explanation... please if you need more info or direct contact just let me know

Comment: i also se something i can't figure out yet, when using auto height.. having the constraints on label top and bottom works ... adding constraints to an image .. left , top, works. but if i add a constraint from the image to bottom (in this case i needed as i want everything to be centered horizontally..) then the label with the word-wrap and autosize doesn't work, i do not get the 2nd line ...

Comment: ill be preparing a sale project today and share :D thnx

Comment: @EICaptain can you help me out with some sample code. i still have this issue. and i also need quick help with attaching a WKWebView to a parent view and fill it completely programmatically, please let me know..

Comment: what version of xcode do you use?